# The practical use of productPrefix def in Product.scala trait

Tags: scala, generics, types

Maybe silly question, but I can't find any useful explanation about this. I've read the documentation, but I'm confused, maybe one use is to compare types, at some extent. Any idea or practical example?

> Blockquote
>
> A string used in the toString methods of derived classes. Implementations may override this method to prepend a string prefix to the result of toString methods.
> Returns:
> in the default implementation, the empty string
> Blockquote

Comment: When you do `final case class Foo(data: Int)` the compiler automatically overrides `productPrefix` to be `"Foo"` and that is used internally by `toString` - if you are asking when you would use that, probably never.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Re "never": `case class UniversalQuantification(binder: String, body: String) { override def productPrefix = "\u2200" }; println(UniversalQuantification("x", "P(x)"))` looks pretty damn neat though: `∀(x,P(x))` :P  Maybe it's actually somewhat useful for printing out ASTs a bit more compactly, while keeping the class names typable.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that is a neat trick, not gonna line. But actually, I meant more you calling that method yourself not overriding it _(although I wasn't clear)_. - Now, it actually may be useful to call that on some kind of very simple serialization library or something; as the saying goes _"never say never"_.

Comment: `override def productPrefix = "\u2200"`, holy macaroni, this is cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples (which extend `Product`) are printed like this:

```
(x1, ..., xN)
^                  opening parenthesis
 ^                 elements
   ^               commas
            ^      closing parenthesis
```

Case classes (which also extend `Product`) are printed like this:

```
CaseClassName(x1, ..., xN)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^                    class name
             ^                   opening parenthesis
              ^                  elements
                ^                commas
                         ^       closing parenthesis
```

Since both inherit from `Product`, it's possible to provide a default `toString` implementation once in the `Product`-trait, which produces something like:

```
${productPrefix}(x1, ..., xN)   // ascii-art, not actual code
```

with `productPrefix = ""` in the case of tuples and `productPrefix = "CaseClassName"` for case classes.

Given that `Tuple`s are such an integral part of the language, I could imagine that using the inheritance of a method implementation from the `Product` trait could have served an actual purpose of "dogfooding" in the earliest phases of the compiler development: this might actually be one of the first and one of the simplest uses of `trait`s. *(It seems somewhat plausible to me, but it's purely speculative; I did not attempt to dig into the commit history.)*

Otherwise, there is no deeper meaning in it. It's just a part of the `toString` implementation. You should never rely on the `toString` implementation for anything, and you should never use it for any kind of program logic.